# How do you balance fun feature creep with time constraints?

Tags: project-management

I enjoy programming, usually.  Tedious stuff is easy to get done as quickly and correctly as possible so I can get through it and not have to see it again.

But a lot of my coding is *fun* and when I get in the 'zone' I just really enjoy myself.

Which is where I make the mistake of spending too much time, perhaps adding features, perhaps writing it in a cool or elegant manner, or just doing neat prototypes.

- How do you recognize this is happening before it exceeds your time frame?
- What do you do before starting a potentially fun piece of code, or during, to get back on track?
- When is it ok to let yourself go "hog wild" and just enjoy it without worrying about consequences?

-Adam

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep a detailed prioritized feature list/bug list.  review it often then balance the fun work with bugs/features that need to get done.

Comment: All of these answers are great advice. This one in particular is well put (albeit somewhat vague). The only thing that I might add is this: always aim for the [minimum viable product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_viable_product). After you make the list that @simon mentions, go through each item and ask yourself (1) is the feature, as a whole, absolutely necessary? And/or (2) can it be reduced to a more basic feature.

Answer (score 4):

Give yourself a hard deadline--even for your own projects. Otherwise, you'll just keep tweaking and adding features ad infinitum.

Answer (score 4):

Always have a working release (snapshot) ready. Treat it like the way SQL server implement snapshot isolation. :)

Continue adding new cool stuffs to a separate copy of the project. Once it is stable, overwrite your release folder and that is your new snapshot. Whenever somebody ask for a demo or release, that way you can always switch to the stable application and will have something to show anytime.

Answer (score 2):

With a backlog. That way you'll always have in mind what *needs* to be done before you can start doing what you *want* to do.

Answer (score 1):

Justify any "fun" features you insert by regarding them as marketable eye-candy.

Unless, of course, they're not visible  ;)

Comment: But all the _really_ cool stuff isn't visible!  Well, mostly.  I loves me some algorithms!  OM NOM NOM NOM NOM...